# Construct a sequence with three limit points

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Couldn't I just say:$$a_n:=\begin{cases}0, \quad \text{if } n \text{ is even } \\ 1, \quad \text{if } n \text{ is uneven} \\ -1 \quad \text{if } n \text{ is prime}\end {cases}$$ As far as I am concerend this should be fine?

Comment: What happens when $n=3,$ for example?

Comment: you're right, this wouldn't work...! thanks.

Comment: Just write the exact same thing except with $n\equiv0,1,2\mod{3}$

Comment: $a_n := n \bmod 3$

Answer (score 2):

This sequence is ill-defined, if you look at e.g. $n=3.$ You can modify your attempt slightly to get a perfectly valid example, though. You can take $$a_n=\begin{cases} 0 &\text{ if  } n=3k, \text{ for some } k\in\mathbb{Z}\\ 1 &\text{ if  } n=3k+1, \text{ for some } k\in\mathbb{Z}\\ -1 &\text{ if  } n=3k+2, \text{ for some } k\in\mathbb{Z}
\end{cases}$$ That is, as @PeterForeman simultaneously suggested, if $n\equiv 0,1,2\text{ mod }3,$ respectively.

Comment: That's fine, thanks!

Comment: No problem! $\ $

Answer (score 1):

You can also take 
$$a_n=\cos(\frac{2n\pi}{3})$$